# Set Intersection with add operation

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, suppose I have:

```
list1=[
 {name='Mark',count='3'}
 {name='Harry',count='2'}
]

list2=[
 {name='John',count='3'}
 {name='Mark',count='1'}
]

list3=[
 {name='John',count='3'}
 {name='Harry',count='1'}
]
```

and I want an intersection of the list that adds "count" of the same "name" items
result:

```
listResult=[
 {name='Mark',count='4'}
 {name='Harry',count='3'}
 {name='John',count='6'}
```

How would I proceed?

Comment: This isn't valid JS

Comment: *"How would I proceed?"* A *good old loop* can do the job. Anything you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create a map of the name counts, then use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to return the desired result.

We first of all concatenate the lists ([list1, list2, list2].flat()), then use .reduce to create our map keyed on item name.

```js
const list1=[ {name:'Mark',count:'3'}, {name:'Harry',count:'2'} ]
const list2=[ {name:'John',count:'3'}, {name:'Mark',count:'1'} ]
const list3=[ {name:'John',count:'3'}, {name:'Harry',count:'1'} ]

const result = Object.values([list1, list2, list3].flat().reduce((acc, curr) => { 
    if (!acc[curr.name]) acc[curr.name] = { name: curr.name, count: 0};
    acc[curr.name].count += (+curr.count);
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

The json above are not valid, but here i got what you wanted.

Have a look below

```js
var list1=[
 {name:'Mark',count:'3'},
 {name:'Harry',count:'2'}
]

var list2=[
 {name:'John',count:'3'},
 {name:'Mark',count:'1'}
]

var list3=[
 {name:'John',count:'3'},
 {name:'Harry',count:'1'}
]
var result = [];
function counter(list){
  list.forEach(x=>{
    var f = result.find(a=> a.name == x.name);
    if (f)
     f.count=parseInt(f.count)+parseInt(x.count);
     else result.push(x);
  })
  
  return result;
}
counter(list1)
counter(list2)
counter(list3)

console.log(result)
```